# Can't access element attributes using XPath axes

Tags: marklogic

I'm not sure why I cannot get the latitude and longitude attributes from the elements. I can access the value from date.

**Query Console:**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace md = "http://mynamespace";

for $row in /md:row

let $date := $row/md:date/text()
let $latitude := fn:string($row/md:geocode/attribute::latitude)
let $longitude := fn:string($row/md:geocode/@longitude)

return (
  <tr>    
    <td>{$date}</td>       
    <td>{$latitude}</td>        
    <td>{$longitude}</td>    
  </tr>
)
```

**XML File Example:**

```
<row _id="555" _uuid="01A580BD-49CB-41DD-8D4C-C83C6E86C688" _position="555" xmlns="http://mynamespace">
  <type>NFS</type>
  <date>2013-10-11T00:00:00</date>  
  <time>134</time>
  <location>100 Penn St</location>
  <city>Baltimore</city>
  <county>Balto. City</county>
  <zip>21201</zip>
  <geocode human_address="{"address":"100 Penn St","city":"Baltimore","state":"","zip":"21201"}" latitude="39.28747052900047" longitude="-76.62597468299964" needs_recoding="false">
  </geocode>
</row>
```

Comment: Works just fine for me, I am getting `<tr><td>2013-10-11T00:00:00</td><td>39.28747052900047</td><td>-76.62597468299964</td></tr>`. Sure you run the exact code against the correct documents?

Comment: Note: the XML looks ill-formed. The double-quotes from the JSON inside the human_address attribute should be escaped. Perhaps repairing the XML makes mistakes because of that? I got the correct result after properly coding the XML..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It works without a namespace for some reason.

Comment: The same one from the example. There are several hundred xml documents with the same namespace. If I add the documents without a namespace then it works, but doesn't work if the documents were added with a namespace. I can retrieve the element with the namespace, but I can't get the value of the attribute.

Comment: Attributes without prefix are in no-namespace, even if a default namespace is specified. Your xpaths should work. But like I said before, perhaps you need to fix that JSON inside the human_address attribute. Have you looked into that yet?

Comment: Taking the human_address out doesn't work either. I've tried this with ML's Centos hand's on training Virtual Box and I get the same result. No values inside the element displays in the browser if I use the code in an index.xqy file without declaring a namespace, but the values will show if I declare a namespace. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: I ended up cleaning up and rebuilding the latitude and longitude into it's own elements. Thanks again!